# Nested elements with transitions in RactiveJS -- How to deal?

Tags: ractivejs

How can I prevent intro and outro transitions from happening when adding or removing a larger chunk of a page? For example:

```
{{#if foo}}
<div intro-outro="fade">
   Welcome to my cool section
   {{#if bar}}
   <div intro-outro="slide">
   Here's a single piece of that section
   </div>
   {{/if}}
</div>
{{/if}}
```

When I set **foo=false**, I see the **bar** block sliding away as the entire **foo** block fades out. I can't imagine when someone would want this as the desired behavior. Am I doing something wrong? How do you deal with nested blocks that each have transitions?

Comment: To clarify the question a bit... If I have a larger block that has an outro transition. And that block contains smaller blocks with individual outro transitions, how can I remove the larger containing block -- as a whole -- without also triggering all the individual outro transitions of the contained blocks?

Comment: Have you tried just using {{#foo}} instead of {{#if foo}}?